# Script Returns empty dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I tried make my own script for pulling values from futbin.com, however it would appear that my dataframes always end up empty when running it and I am not sure why.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Define the URL to scrape
URL = 'https://www.futbin.com/players?page=1&version=all_versions'
TIMEOUT = 20

# Send a GET request to the URL and parse the HTML content
response = requests.get(URL, timeout=TIMEOUT)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Find all the player cards on the page
player_cards = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'playercard'})

# Create lists to store the player names and values
player_names = []
player_values = []

# Loop through each player card and extract the name and value
for card in player_cards:
    name = card.find('a', {'class': 'player_name_players_table'}).text.strip()
    value = int(
        card.find('span', {'class': 'pc_color'}).text.strip().replace(',', ''))
    player_names.append(name)
    player_values.append(value)

# Create a dictionary with the player names and values
data = {'Name': player_names, 'Value': player_values}

# Create a pandas dataframe from the dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the dataframe
print(df)
```

Although I tried debugging I am clueless as to what my code is missing or what is going wrong. Sorry if I am missing something obvious as I am not very experienced and just tried this as a small experiment.

Comment: Hello, one question class playercard is in the html source? Searching it in html code doesn't return any result...

Comment: find_all is not returning anything.

Comment: you are getting an 403 code from your response...